# Is there a convenient way to print values to a JS chart from a CSV file without converting it?

Tags: javascript, json, csv, charts, chart.js

I saw this code on JSFIDDLE:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Chart.js chart from a CSV</title>


    <style>
      html, body {
        font-family: "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
      }
      /* Same as .flex-auto in Tachyons except without the 'auto' flex-basis */
      .flex-fill {
        flex: 1 1;
        min-width: 0; /* 1 */
        min-height: 0; /* 1 */
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="top"></div>

    <div id="app" class="tc">
      <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    </div>

    

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flexio-sdk-js@latest"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      var renderChart = function(data) {
        var chart_data = formatDataForChart(data)
        var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d')
        window.my_chart = new Chart(ctx, {
          type: 'bar',
          data: chart_data,
          options: {
            responsive: true,
            legend: {
              position: 'top'
            },
            title: {
              display: true,
              text: 'Use Flex.io to Create a chart with Chart.js firectly from a CSV file'
            }
          }
        })
      }
      var formatDataForChart = function(content) {
        var first_item = _.get(content, '[0]', {})
        var column_labels = _.map(_.omit(first_item, ['os']), function(val, key) {
          if (key != 'os')
          return key
        })
        // use Lodash to reformat the JSON for use with Chart.js
        var datasets = _.map(content, function(item) {
          // use the 'os' column as our label
          var item_label = _.get(item, 'os', 'Not Found')
          // create an array of number values from each item's JSON object
          var item_values = _.map(_.omit(item, ['os']), function(val) {
          return parseFloat(val)
          })
          return {
          label: item_label,
          data: item_values,
          backgroundColor: getRandomColor()
          }
        })
        var chart_data = {
          labels: column_labels,
          datasets: datasets
        }
        return chart_data
      }
      var getRandomColor = function() {
        var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('')
        var color = '#'
        for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
          color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)]
        }
        return color
      }
      Flexio.setup('rryrjgqhvtdttzzsjpjr')
      Flexio.pipe()
        // request the content of the URL that is specified
        .request('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flexiodata/examples/master/demo-chartjs-from-csv/source-data/phone-market-share.csv')
        // convert the above CSV-formatted text into JSON
        .convert('csv','json')
        .run(function(err, response) {
          var data = JSON.parse(response.text)
          renderChart(data)
        })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

It's a chart that uses CSV data, but converts it to JSON before doing so. I'm hoping to make a chart that graphs CSV data from a url file without that extra conversion. Now, I am a newbie to Javascript, so I was hoping for some assistance and would greatly appreciate it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is a Chart.js plugin [chartjs-plugin-datasource](https://nagix.github.io/chartjs-plugin-datasource/) that makes it easy to load data from CSV files. By default, each row in a CSV file will be mapped to one dataset, and the first column and the first row will be treated as dataset labels and index labels respectively. You can also customize how to parse CSV data using options.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datasource@0.1.0"> </script>

<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    plugins: [ChartDataSource],
    options: {
        daatasource: {
            url: 'phone-market-share.csv'
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: `daatasource` is that a spelling mistake?

Answer (score 1):

I mean, if you've got the csv string, let's assume that the variable is `csv`

```
OS,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017
Android,1.6,9.6,36.4,56.9,74.4,80.8,78.8,84.1,86.1
iOS,10.5,15.4,16.9,22.5,18.2,15.3,17.9,14.8,13.7
Microsoft,10.2,6.8,2.6,1.9,2.9,2.7,2.5,0.7,0.1
RIM,20.6,19.7,13,6.8,3,0.6,0.4,0.2,0
Symbian,48.8,44.2,27.7,8.5,0.6,0.2,0.1,0,0
```

first split it by newlines and then split it by commas like so.

```
const array = csv.split('\n').map(col => col.split(','));
```

Comment: I'm gonna call the CSV file from a url, not as a string directly in the program

Comment: @ManaalSiddiqui that really doesn't make sense. The data has to get to the same place as the chart and be passed to the chart. How you get it there is a bit irrelevant

Comment: @ManaalSiddiqui, I'm not sure if I understand what you mean by "call from a URL" but I figure that the Javascript needs to fetch the string to process it somewhere within the code. These are just the steps you need to take when you have the string.